# Should I buy everything that woot! is selling?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I the only person to find the woot ad noxious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24185/am-i-the-only-person-to-find-the-woot-ad-noxious)

Yes, I hate ads that try to fool you by blending into the site. I even clicked on it.

Now, the question is, do you think this (common) practice is ethical and would you employ it on your own websites? I won't lie, I think these ads are cute, but the fact of the matter is that you're tricking your users to go buy items from other people - potentially you profit from it but you begin to lose user trust when you do something like that. Or is it okay in small amounts?

EDIT: And for those of you that don't understand, Stack Overflow now has an ad that looks almost exactly like actual questions. I made the mistake of thinking the first one was some sort of weird "featured" question.

Comment: I did see this add!  It did fool me... i am broke... penny-less...

Comment: Use adblock, etc...

Comment: @LiraNuna AdBlock kills the web.

Comment: @Isaac Waller: Oh come off it.