# Vomit inducing advertisements

Tags: discussion, advertising

Am I the only one reduced to a state of nausea by the Intel adverts appearing on SO? Someone should tell them that "Developer Rock Star" is not a term of approbation. Perhaps Jeff & Co could set up a little consultancy on how to appeal to real developers.

Comment: Can't we all just unite on the "Case of the Mondays?" ad first???

Comment: Get rid of the sexist/entomonist ad first! Down with sexism! Down with entomonism!

Comment: Back when SO was having serious slowness issues due to the ads, I added ads.stackoverflow.com to my hosts file and made it point to some arbitrary location.  I've never looked back :-P (sorry, Jeff!)

Comment: [It could be worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/has-anyone-clicked-the-new-woot-ads/25941#25941)

Comment: @perbert It could have been Evony!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had that problem in at least two years. That's when I started using the Firefox plugin `Adblock plus`. Pages load so much faster and spam free.

Comment: I too use adblock, but the damn things have started appearing again! I must have changed something without noticing it, I suppose.

Comment: Upon installation (or through adblock config) you may subscribe to an ever updating list. I use EasyListUSA I think.

Comment: yes, I also use Adblock Plus, and it works great, I have yet to see a graphic ad on any of the Trilogy sites - Using EasyListUSA...be sure to update your subscriptions regularly