# What's behind these strange adverts posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, advertising

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
>   [Am I the only person to find the woot ad noxious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24185/am-i-the-only-person-to-find-the-woot-ad-noxious)

Does this count as abuse of the way ads should work?

[image]

Comment: @Dafydd Rees: it's a joke! And the really obnoxious ads were the ones that came after there was an uproar because of this one. And it had a bigger click rate. We have only ourselves to blame. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/has-anyone-clicked-the-new-woot-ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ironically self aware and genre-savvy advertising. It's clear that they're both a) trying to mimic the site design in order to attract more attention, and b) making sure that the content is different enough (by calling attention to their own whorish nature) that they can't be accused of abuse.

Comment: So it works on the "there's no such thing as bad publicity" principle. ;-)